# How do you configure Eclipse with Python & GAE for integrated debugging?

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am a Python newbie so first let me apologize in advance if this question was answered elsewhere - I searched and could not find an answer.  When using Java/Eclipse/GAE, I was easily able to use Eclipse's integrated debugging facilities, but I had no such debugger joy with Python.

What I'd like to be able to do is:

1. Set breakpoints in my Python code by clicking the debugger circle in the Eclipse editor window of my Python source
2. Set up a debug configuration so I can hit the debug button in Eclipse and have Eclipse launch my Python/GAE app locally in debug mode and break on my breakpoint
3. Let me single-step within the Eclipse IDE and examine variables as I'm stepping

Through proper configuration of the PythonPath I can get code completion working, but can't get the debugging environment plugged in.

As I searched around, it appears many people recommend using logging and/or the command line, which I could certainly do too but I would prefer to use the integrated Eclipse debugging capabilities if possible.

Could someone please explain to this Python newbie how to get some Python/GAE/Eclipse debugger joy, or point me to an article explaining how to do this?  Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not trying to be controversial here (otherwise I'd put it as an answer and not a comment), but try looking at other python IDEs... Personally, I use pycharm (or intellij) and haven't looked back since.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this guide on setting up PyDev with Eclipse:
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the steps from: http://pydev.blogspot.com/2009/05/testing-on-pydev-146-google-app-engine.html ? (it walks you from configuring PyDev to debugging and deploying your app from inside PyDev)